# Assigning integer values to strings in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a card game I am trying to make. Most of it works but I am having trouble figuring out an effective way to assign integer values to the string elements I have in my arrays. Essentially I have an `ArrayList` with each card in a standard deck and two get drawn every turn. Even though they are strings (Ace of Spades, etc.) I need them to somehow have a numerical value so the two cards can be compared to determine a winner (Jack beats 7, etc.). I have given it an attempt that I think should be able to work but does not.

```
boolean checkAce = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Ace");
boolean checkTwo = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Two");
boolean checkThree = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Three");
boolean checkFour = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Four");
boolean checkFive = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Five");
boolean checkSix = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Six");
boolean checkSeven = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Seven");
boolean checkEight = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Eight");
boolean checkNine = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Nine");
boolean checkTen = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Ten");
boolean checkJack = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Jack");
boolean checkQueen = deckList.get(0).startsWith("Queen");
boolean checkKing = deckList.get(0).startsWith("King");

boolean checkAceP2 = deckList.get(1).startsWith("Ace");
boolean checkTwoP2 = deckList.get(1).startsWith("Two");
boolean checkThreeP2 = deckList.get(1).startsWith("Three");
boolean checkFourP2 = deckList.get(1).startsWith("Four");
boolean checkFiveP2 = deckList.get(1).startsWith("Five");
boolean checkSixP2 = deckList.get(1).startsWith("Six");
boolean checkSevenP2 = deckList.get(1).startsWith("Seven");
boolean checkEightP2 = deckList.get(1).startsWith("Eight");
boolean checkNineP2 = deckList.get(1).startsWith("Nine");
boolean checkTenP2 = deckList.get(1).startsWith("Ten");
boolean checkJackP2 = deckList.get(1).startsWith("Jack");
boolean checkQueenP2 = deckList.get(1).startsWith("Queen");
boolean checkKingP2 = deckList.get(1).startsWith("King");

int playerOneScore = 0;
int playerTwoScore = 0;

if (checkAce = true) {
    playerOneScore = 14;
}else if (checkTwo = true) {
    playerOneScore = 2;
}else if (checkThree = true) {
    playerOneScore = 3;
}else if (checkFour = true) {
    playerOneScore = 4;
}else if (checkFive = true) {
    playerOneScore = 5;
}else if (checkSix = true) {
    playerOneScore = 6;
}else if (checkSeven = true) {
    playerOneScore = 7;
}else if (checkEight = true) {
    playerOneScore = 8;
}else if (checkNine = true) {
    playerOneScore = 9;
}else if (checkTen = true) {
    playerOneScore = 10;
}else if (checkJack = true) {
    playerOneScore = 11;
}else if (checkQueen = true) {
    playerOneScore = 12;
}else if (checkKing = true) {
    playerOneScore = 13;
}

if (checkAceP2 = true) {
    playerTwoScore = 14;
}else if (checkTwoP2 = true) {
    playerTwoScore = 2;
}else if (checkThreeP2 = true) {
    playerTwoScore = 3;
}else if (checkFourP2 = true) {
    playerTwoScore = 4;
}else if (checkFiveP2 = true) {
    playerTwoScore = 5;
}else if (checkSixP2 = true) {
    playerTwoScore = 6;
}else if (checkSevenP2 = true) {
    playerTwoScore = 7;
}else if (checkEightP2 = true) {
    playerTwoScore = 8;
}else if (checkNineP2 = true) {
    playerTwoScore = 9;
}else if (checkTenP2 = true) {
    playerTwoScore = 10;
}else if (checkJackP2 = true) {
    playerTwoScore = 11;
}else if (checkQueenP2 = true) {
    playerTwoScore = 12;
}else if (checkKingP2 = true) {
    playerTwoScore = 13;
}

if (playerOneScore > playerTwoScore) {
    System.out.println("Player One Wins!");
}else if (playerTwoScore > playerOneScore) {
    System.out.println("Player Two Wins!");
}else if (playerOneScore == playerTwoScore) {
    System.out.println("Tie");
}
```

The idea behind this is that every loop I preform to deal the cards will check the `ArrayList` Element to see if the beginning matches the string of the face value. Then an `if` statement checks to see which one is true and assigns the appropriate points to the score value for each player and compares them. For some reason, every time I run it `checkAce` and `checkAceP2` both evaluate to `true` no matter what cards are actually at `deckList.get(0)` and `.get(1)`. This results in a tie each time. Can anyone see the flaw in my code? Or can anyone recommend a better method for achieving my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(checkAce = true)` assigns `true` to `checkAce` and (as a side-effect) *evaluates* to true. You need `==` or just the boolean (for all of your `if`s).

```
if (checkAce == true)
```

**or** the shorter

```
if (checkAce)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer

> I am having trouble figuring out an effective way to assign integer values to the string elements I have in my arrays.

I would use an Enumeration instead of a String if possible since the value of each card is going to be constant. Then, instead of having an ArrayList of Strings, you'd have an ArrayList of Cards.

```
public enum Card {
    ACE(14),
    ONE(1),
    TWO(2),
    ...
    KING(13);

    /** The point value associated to each card. */
    private int pointValue;

    private Card(int pointValue) {
        this.pointValue = pointValue;
    }

    public int getPointValue() {
        return this.pointValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: A "card" is usually a combination of "rank" (e.g. Queen) and "suit" (e.g. Hearts).

Comment: Agreed. If OP is strictly concerned about differentiating point values, then the suit attribute isn't useful in this scenario (Assuming all suits of a card have equal point values).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you store a Card as as String. A Card is usually represented as an Object with two attributes: Rank and Suit.

The String representation of a card is easy to build from the Rank and Suit. Extracting the Rank and Suit from a String is however not as easy, especially if your card game becomes popular and needs to be translated to other languages. It is also much slower than the other way around.

So I would say that your trouble is that you started wrong. Create a Card class with a Rank field and a Suit field. Both fields could benefit from being enums:

```
public enum Rank { TWO, THREE, ... , JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE }
public enum Suit { SPADES, HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS }
public class Card {
    public final Rank rank;
    public final Suit suit;
    public Card(Rank rank, Suit suit) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Or make the fields `private` and add getter methods.

This way your code become easier:

```
if (deckList.get(0).rank == Rank.ACE) {
```

And printing a card (or the entire `deckList`) will still show the full text, such as "Queen of Hearts", courtesy of the `toString()` method.